# Why should a Cauchy surface be closed?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, causality, topology

A Cauchy surface is defined on any spacetime $M$ as a subset $S$ which is closed, achronal, and whose domain of dependence $D(S) = M$.

Why do we include the "closed" condition in the above definition? Is it for technical reasons (to make calculations easier), or is there any intuitive explanation for this?

Comment: I *think* Figure 8.8 of Wald is an example of a spacetime with a non-closed achronal subset $S$ whose domain of dependence is $M$;  namely, let $S$ be the null geodesic drawn through the point $p$ in that figure.  But that spacetime isn't strongly causal.  So I suspect that without $S$ being closed, you don't have the equivalence of "a Cauchy surface exists" and "the spacetime is strongly causal."

Comment: (That said, it's been a while since I thought about these issues which is why the above is a comment rather than an answer.  I'll think about it further and write it up if I'm convinced or comment again if I spot a flaw in my reasoning.)

Comment: This question concerns Mathematical Physics of General Relativity. I cannot see a reason for closing it. Unless thinking, for instance, that Wald’s book on GR is mathematics.

Comment: Upon further reflection I don't think that $D^+(S) = M$ in the case I've given because one could find a past-directed causal curve from some points in the upper part of the diagram that "should" go through the missing point.  Such a curve would be past-inextendible without intersecting $S$.

Comment: The definition given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_surface) does not include the "closed", the property "closed" is instead presented as a consequence.

Comment: Could you please provide a source for the definition to allow to understand the context, e.g. the author's definition of "domain of dependence"?

Answer (score 2):

"Closed" is not necessary, as [Witten](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03928v6) argues (Pg 18): a subset $S$ which is achronal, and whose domain of dependence $D(S)=M$ must be necessarily closed. The inclusion of the requirement that the set be closed is just because those authors first would have defined *Domain of Dependence* for only closed sets, because defining it for an open set seems not to be useful. Hawking & Ellis mention in section 6.5 "Cauchy developments" of their book,

> "Thus a knowledge of the appropriate data on a closed set $\mathcal{S}$ (if one knew data on an open set, that on its closure would follow by continuity) would determine events in a region $D^+(\mathcal S)$ to the future of $\mathcal S$ called the *future Cauchy development* or *domain of dependence* of $\mathcal S$..."

Comment: Doesn't Witten only discuss Cauchy hypersurfaces and not Cauchy subsets?

Comment: A hypersurface is a subset of the full manifold.

Comment: But not every subset is a hyperspace. Results about Cauchy hyperspaces may not hold for Cauchy subsets in general.

Comment: Your question talks about Cauchy surfaces. The word "hypersurface" just means that it is a surface of codimension 1. Since a Cauchy surface necessarily has to be a surface of codimension 1, these are just two words for the same thing.